# Node Demo API request not generating email

Tags: docusignapi

I'm able to generate the document: 
[image]

But they are not showing up as requiring action, nor are emails being generated for them:
[image]

For reference they were sent to myself (same email)

Answer (score 0):

Check your spam folder and also make sure the emails aren't getting stopped by security software, firewalls, or any other type of network filtering.  Try testing with external email addresses to help debug as well, for instance use a gmail or yahoo email etc.

Comment: I've tested with external email accounts and am having the same issue. The spam and junk folders are clear. How would the emails be getting stopped?